# Passing json to MVC controller and deserializing

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, model-binding

I have a VS2015 asp.net MVC (not core) application.

I have a razor view that uses javascript to post data to a controller from the following function, bound to a Button on the view using KonockoutJS:

```
self.resubmit = function () {
    var data = { Recs: ko.toJS(this.recs) };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: BASE_URL + 'EditBatch/Resubmit',
        data: ko.toJSON(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            window.location = BASE_URL + 'EditBatch/Index';
        },
        error: function (data) {
            toastrs(false);
        }
    });
}
```

The view should enable to the user to change data in four fields from dozens that are contained within each record. The user is only presented with the fields they are allowed to change. My plan is for the controller to receive data from the editable fields along with the rest of the data from the record - it will then figure out what to replace before submitting for processing by BizTalk.

I have a binding problem!

Here's the data that's being sent from the view to the controller, clipped from Fiddler:

[image: fiddler]

Here's the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
//Called by the Knockout View Model to update db
public void Resubmit(EditBatchViewModel vm)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    ABWTransaction abwTran = jss.Deserialize<ABWTransaction>(vm.Recs[0].WholeRecInJson);

    RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And the view model:

```
public class EditBatchViewModel
{
    public List<VmEditBatch> Recs { get; set; }
    public EditBatchViewModel()
    {
        Recs = new List<VmEditBatch>();
    }
}
public class VmEditBatch
{
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string VoucherNo { get; set; }
    public string WholeRecInJson { get; set; }
}
```

Trouble is, although data from the editable fields is reaching the controller, the remaining data that is being posted in the "wholeRecInJson" field is not being bound, as can be seen from my Locals window in VS after placing a breakpoint on the first line of the controller action:

[image: locals]

Where did I go wrong please?

Comment: The problem is that the `WholeRecInJson` property is defined as a `string` in your model but is actually a complex object as per the data sent. Simply declaring it as a string won't magically cause the JS framework to just give the JSON representation of it to you.

Comment: Ah ok, so is there a way to serialise to a string before it's sent?

Comment: Well, why are you calling ko.toJS in your submit function? What is the type of "this.recs" before you do that? If you remove ko.toJS and send it as a string instead it should then be received as a string on the server side.